# Template object being passed throws a sanitize error in Meteor

Tags: node.js, meteor

This code pulls field values from a form, and I can see the values being passed properly when I debug in the console. However, due to the extra object added with my first value, Meteor throws a sanitize error...any ideas?

```
Template.sendInvitationModal.events({
'submit form': function submitForm(event, template) {
   event.preventDefault();

   var firstName = template.find("[name='firstName']").value,
       lastName = template.find("[name='lastName']").value,
       email = template.find("[name='emailAddress']").value,
       store = template.find("[name='store'] option:selected").value,
       position = template.find("[name='position'] option:selected").value,
       roles = template.find("[name='roles'] option:selected").value;

    debugger;

  if (email && roles && position !== "") {
    Meteor.call("sendInvitation", {
    firstName: firstName,
    lastName: lastName,
    email: email,
    store: store,
    position: position,
    roles: roles
  }, function (error, response) {
    if (error) {
        toastr["warning"]( error.reason);
    } else {
      $("#send-invitation-modal").modal('hide');
      $('.modal-backdrop').hide();
      toastr["success"]( "Invitation sent!" );
    }
  });
} else {
  toastr["warning"]( "Please set an email and at least one user type!" );
}}});
```

This is the value being passed with firstName when calling "sendInvitation"

```
firstName = "Richard", template = B…e.TemplateInstance {view: B…e.View, data: Object, firstNode: div#send-invitation-modal.modal.fade.in, lastNode: div#send-invitation-modal.modal.fade.in, _allSubsReadyDep: T…r.Dependency…}
```

And then Meteor throws a sanitize error. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We managed (thanks Ryan Glover for your assistance) to find a solution by simply converting the variables assignment from the values pulled out of the form into an object instead. Solved it! So the correct code is...

```
Template.sendInvitationModal.events({
'submit form': function submitForm(event, template) {
  event.preventDefault();

  var data = {
    firstName: template.find("[name='firstName']").value,
    lastName: template.find("[name='lastName']").value,
    email: template.find("[name='emailAddress']").value,
    store: template.find("[name='store'] option:selected").value,
    position: template.find("[name='position'] option:selected").value,
    roles: template.find("[name='roles'] option:selected").value
  };

  if (data.email && data.roles && data.position !== "") {
    Meteor.call("sendInvitation", data, function (error, response) {
      if (error) {
        toastr["warning"]( error.reason);
      } else {
        $("#send-invitation-modal").modal('hide');
        $('.modal-backdrop').hide();
        toastr["success"]( "Invitation sent!" );
      }
    });
  } else {
    toastr["warning"]( "Please set an email and at least one user type!" );
  }
}
});
```